# Первые шаги в typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

В коде я часто использую функцию как объект, то есть:

```
let a = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

a.b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

a.c = function () {
    console.log('c');
}

a(); -> a
a.b(); -> b
a.c(); -> c
```

В typescript такой синтаксис не проходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему и что делать ?

Comment: Ээээ, а какой смысл укладывать полем функции другую функцию? Какую жизненную ситуацию это моделирует?

Comment: @OlmerDale Это адресовано мне на вопрос ? Или на верхний комментарий? Если же мне, то потрудитесь объяснить почему, с вашей точки зрения, нельзя ?

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо описать вызываемый интерфейс:

```
interface Func {
  (): void
  b(): void
  c(): void
}

const a: Func = () => console.log('a')
a.b = () => console.log('b')
a.c = () => console.log('c')
```

Answer (score 0):

поставить тип `void` можно, чтоб обозначить, что будут свойства, которые ничего не будут возвращать

```
let a:void  = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

a.b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

a.c = function () {
    console.log('c');
}

a(); 
a.b();
a.c();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrzgRe

Либо можно поставить `any` — может понадобиться если нужно описать тип переменных, которые мы не знаем, когда пишем приложение.

```
let a:any = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

a.b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

a.c = function () {
    console.log('c');
}

a(); 
a.b();
a.c();
```

Вообще выглядит это странно: функция,  а у нее поля еще функции О_о

Может быть вы хотели сделать так:

```
class A {    
    constructor() {
        // do smth
    }

    b() {
        console.log("b");
    }

    c() {
        console.log("c");
    }
}

let myClass = new A();       

myClass.b();
myClass.c();
```

Comment: Строго говоря с `:void` не работает https://hkar.ru/OBRG
Но если писать так https://hkar.ru/OBRM то всё как надо, но я не понимаю в чем смысл добавления переменной is типа :any если там хранится функция ?

Comment: "Вообще выглядит это странно: функция, а у нее поля еще функции О_о", если не лазить глубоко есть маленькая библиотека и её нужно переписать https://hkar.ru/OBS5

Answer (score -1):

Незнаю будет вам удобно или нет, но можете поробовать статические методы.

```
class A{
    static b(){
        console.log("b")
    }

    static c(){
        console.log("c")
    }
}

A.b()
A.c()
```

С типом `any`

```
let a:any = function(){
    console.log("a")
}

a.b = function(){
    console.log("b")
}
a.c = function(){
    console.log("c")
}

a()
a.b()
a.c()
```

Comment: Я уже думал об этом, но в таком случае я в не могу вызвать конструктор

Comment: А зачем статик если можно не статик? `let test = new A();       
test.b();
test.c();`

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин в смысле не можете вызвать конструктор? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmNqMw

Comment: @Станислав Далинин если хотите использовать синтаксис JS то можете использовать тип `any`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 

"`let test = new A(); test.b(); test.c();`" сейчас будет не актуальный пример для typescript но как пример хороший, у меня есть функция let is = (d)  =>  typeof d;
и еще к примеру is.array = Array.isArray;

Извиняюсь, "Я уже думал об этом, но в таком случае я в не могу вызвать конструктор" имел ввиду использовать абстрактный класс с статическими методами. Если сделать это классом, что бы узнать тип элемента мне придётся создавать экземпляр класса, мне кажется это мягко говоря не очень красиво.